# RangeValidator doesnt work as expected using specific date

Tags: asp.net, .net, rangevalidator

When I try to submit a specific date "20-10-2013" (international format: 2013-10-20"), rangevalidator throws the error message for invalid date

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDataInicial" runat="server" Width="55px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RangeValidator ID="rgvDtInicial" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDataInicial"
    Display="Static" MinimumValue="01/01/1800" MaximumValue="31/12/9999" Type="Date"
    ErrorMessage="A data inicial, deve ter o seguinte formato: DD/MM/AAAA"
    ValidationGroup="Consultar"></asp:RangeValidator>
<asp:Button ID="btnConsultar" runat="server" Style="width: 150px;" Text="Consultar"
    OnClick="btnConsultar_Click" ValidationGroup="Consultar" />
```

It works for dates like , "19-10-2013", "21-10-2013", "20-10-2014", "20-10-2012".

It just happens when I submit this date!
Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Dates are culture-depended. Specify your culture declaratively in web.config or in a Page directive, or programatically.

Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: It works for dates like , "19-10-2013", "21-10-2013", "20-10-2014", "20-10-2012". And the culture is set properly

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce it. Add this to RangeValidator: EnableClientScript="false". Then check Page.IsValid property on btnConsultar_Click. What does it say when you input "20-10-2013" ? If it is "true", it means that there is something wrong with the client side validation script.

Answer (score 0):

1. Rangevalidator control front end code
   This is the culprit of the error. Make sure the cultureinvariantvalues is set to false.
2. Ensure assigning the correct minimum & maximum date range at code behind.
3. This is to standardise our date comparison to culture="en-GB" which use "dd/mm/yyyy" independent of server localization setting. You may use the "en-US" and the format will be "mm-dd-yyyy".

http://chinteongtan.blogspot.com/2014_04_01_archive.html